# Adding Views to Layout overrides View id

Tags: android, view, android-layout

i want to know if anybody experiments this, i have a Custom View, who draws a Radar, everything is fine, the draw, measurement, layout, but when i construct it i set the view id with an integer like this,

```
Radar radar = new Radar(context);
radar.setId(RADAR_COMPONENT.hashCode());
LayoutParams lParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
lParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
this.addView( radar, lParams );
```

and later i add others views without set the id... like this

```
this.addView( getItemView(item), new LayoutParams(150, 100));
...
this.addView( getItemView(item), new LayoutParams(150, 100));
...
```

the getItemView(item) returns a inflated View from xml without id, and item is the object who holds the view info. My problem is when i add this views the fist view Radar... lost the id, and the id is -1, Anyone experiments this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you are setting the id, also why are you doing this the hard way you can still add your custom views via xml layouts by giving the full class plus package name for the view

Comment: well, i'm setting the id on radar.setId(RADAR_COMPONENT.hashCode()); the others views are inflated from xml layouts and don't have id, they are very simply views, but the radar view are very complex and i cannot build from xml

Comment: what is stopping you from building from xml you are only causing yourself all kinds of extra grief...